# Python: Can someone help me debug this error? [newbie]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a piece of code that's meant to compare two lists (which are read from CSV files) and return the items that are in A and not in B and vice versa.
Here's what I've got:

```
import csv

#open CSV's and read first column with product IDs into variables pointing to lists
with open("A.csv", "rb") as f: 
    a = {row[0] if len(row) else default_value for row in csv.reader(f)}
with open("B.csv", "rb") as g: 
    b = {row[0] if len(row) else default_value for row in csv.reader(g)}


#create variables pointing to lists with unique product IDs in A and B respectively 

in_a_not_b = a-b 
in_b_not_a = b-a 

print len(in_a_not_b), " items in A missing from B", in_a_not_b
print len(in_b_not_a), " items in B missing from A", in_b_not_a


print "done!"
```

It used to run just fine, until I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../python - Comprare two lists", line 7, in <module>
    b = {row[0] if len(row) else default_value for row in csv.reader(g)}
  File "C:/.../python - Comprare two lists", line 7, in <setcomp>
    b = {row[0] if len(row) else default_value for row in csv.reader(g)}
NameError: global name 'default_value' is not defined
```

Can anyone please help ?
Thanks!

Comment: The error has told you. `default_value` not defined.

Comment: You havn't given `default_value` any default value :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a `default_value` variable.

just like your error says:

```
NameError: global name 'default_value' is not defined
```

You should put something like:

```
default_value = None
```

Above the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why did it work so far without a problem ? What changed?

Comment: I am guessing that up to now you never needed it since the row always had a length.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables have now some empty rows, thus the condition

> if len(row)

is now `False` and `default_value` is used but not found.

Comment: Yeah I feel like it's gonna be a full time job to gain reputation ;)

Comment: +1 , this answers the question correctly (You deserve an upvote)